# Generic where you pass to the base class a method invoked from the generic type

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics

New to C# generics, so not sure if I am doing this right, but I get some errors I'd really appreciate help resolving!

```
namespace Microsoft.Outlook.ModernPrototype.ViewModels.ItemListView
{
    public class ConversationMap<T> : Dictionary<T, ConversationListItem>
        where T : ConversationKeyInterface<KeyEqualityInterface<T>>
    {
        public ConversationMap() : base(T.getEquality()) { }    // breaks
    }

    public class KeyEqualityInterface<S> : IEqualityComparer<S> 
        where S : ConversationKeyInterface<S> { }

    public interface ConversationKeyInterface<T>
    {
        static T getEquality();
    }
}
```

Please note where I commented that it breaks.  I reckon I should be using some form of reflection here, but not sure what would be the best method for that here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is actually here:

```
public interface ConversationKeyInterface<T>
{
    static T getEquality();
}
```

You cannot define `static` methods (or properties) in an `interface`.  Interfaces only allow instance members to be defined.

You need to determine some other mechanism for specifying your `IEqualityComparer<T>` in your design.